# Get data back from ajax call within ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm need some help figuring out how to get back data from the second ajax call, not the first.

I have this method that calls my ajax calls

```
var projectWithIssues = getProjects().done(function(result) {
....
}
```

When I look at the results from this, I get back the results on my first ajax call(getEnt_PodType().done()). I want to get the results from the second ajax call within getProjects(). I understand the reason I'm getting the first results back is because I have the return on the first ajax call. However, If I don't have a return there. I get a undefined on the line above. How can I return the data from the second call?

```
function getEnt_PodType() {
var ent_PodType;
var oDataUrl = //URL to my data;
return $.ajax({
    url: oDataUrl,
    type: "GET",
    async: true,
    beforeSend: function (xhr) {
        xhr.setRequestHeader("ACCEPT", accept);
    },
    success: function (xhr, textStatus) { 

    }
});
}


function getProjects() {

return getEnt_PodType().done(function (res) {
    var ent_PodType;

    if (res.d.results != undefined) {
        ent_PodType = res.d.results[0].Ent_PodType;
    }
    console.log("The ent pod type value is " + ent_PodType);

    var QUERY_FILTER = 
        "$filter=Ent_PodType eq '" + ent_PodType + "'";

    var url = restUrl + QUERY_FILTER;

    // I want to return the results from this ajax call
    $.ajax({  
        url: url,
        type: "GET",
        async: true,
        beforeSend: function (xhr) {
            xhr.setRequestHeader("ACCEPT", accept);
        },
        success: function (xhr, textStatus) {
            //projects = parseODataResultTest(xhr);
            //return projects;
        }
    });
});
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You get results from all AJAX calls the same way: in their callback functions. It doesn't matter if it's an inner or outer call. Asynchronous functions can't return anything, because the caller has already moved on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try utilizing pattern found at [deferred.then](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.then/)

```
// first request
var request = $.ajax(url1), 
  chained = request.then(function( data ) {
    console.log(data) // first request response data
    // return second request
    return $.ajax(url2)
  });

chained.then(function( data ) {
  console.log(data) // second request response data
  // data retrieved from url2 as provided by the first request
});
```

```js
    var request = $.ajax("https://gist.githubusercontent.com/guest271314/23e61e522a14d45a35e1/raw/62775b7420f8df6b3d83244270d26495e40a1e9d/ticker.json"), // first request , `html` document
      chained = request.then(function( data ) {
        console.log(data) // `["abc"]`
// return `data` from second request
        return $.ajax("https://gist.githubusercontent.com/guest271314/6a76aa9d2921350c9d53/raw/49fbc054731540fa68b565e398d3574fde7366e9/abc.txt")
      });
     
    chained.then(function( data ) {
      console.log(data) // `abc123`
      // data retrieved from url2 as provided by the first request
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: FWIW, this is pretty much the same as my answer

Comment: @Alnitak Certainly not intended . May not be entirely clear to "see" that `func2` is actually an `$.ajax()` request in the form of something like `function func2() {return $.ajax()`}` ? Perhaps include that fully composed portion at post ?

Comment: @Alnitak fwiw , _"not intended"_ meaning not intended to knock off your post :) Didn't "see" , here , that at initial post , `func2` was returning `$.ajax` call ; same / same. Thanks

Comment: No worries :)   FWIW, I prefer making each `$.ajax` calling function independent, rather than throwing too many anonymous functions into the `.then` chain.

Comment: @Alnitak Yes . Agreed . Posted answer as a basic pattern / template for OP to , perhaps , "see" flow of chaining / sequences

Answer (score 0):

Use `.then` instead of `.done`, it allows better chaining of functions.

Break your code apart so that the two AJAX calls are in separate functions, and have both those functions `return` the result of their `$.ajax` call.  You can then use:

```
func1().then(func2).then(...);
```

`func2` will be passed the result of the first AJAX call, and then the result of *that* will be passed to whatever function is in the final `then`.

In your case you can also put the call to `parseODataResultTest` in the chain and then the final function will (eventually) be called with the required data, i.e.:

```
getEnt_PodType().then(getProjects).then(parseODataResultTest).then(function(projects) {
    // use projects here, and _only_ here because it won't
    // be in scope or defined anywhere else
    ...
});
```